# Initializing System.Array?

Tags: .net, vb.net

Why does Visual Basic compiler complain?

```
Dim finalArray As Array = New Array
```

Comment: Is this a slip of the keyboard and you meant *does complain* ?

Comment: What type of object(s) are you planning to store in the array?

Answer (score 4):

Array is an abstract class ([MustInherit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h8w3a9dz%28VS.80%29.aspx) in VB terms). You cannot instantiate an abstract class.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:**(after Joe Chung remark)

[msdn:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h8w3a9dz(VS.80).aspx)

> A MustInherit class cannot be
>   instantiated directly, and therefore
>   the New operator cannot be used on a
>   MustInherit class. **Although it's
>   possible to have variables and values
>   whose compile time types are
>   MustInherit**, such variables and values
>   will necessarily either be a null
>   value or contain references to
>   instances of regular classes derived
>   from the MustInherit types.

Comment: Actually that is his situation.

Answer (score 2):

As others said, it DOES complain. awe is right, you have to specify the type and size of the array. You can do it with an array initializer:

```
Dim finalArray As Array = New Integer() {1, 2, 3}
```

But when you assign it to an Array, you lose type information. It is better to do:

```
Dim finalArray As Integer() = {1, 2, 3}
```

This way you have an array of integer that you can access by index, and you can still use all the methods of Array.

Answer (score 1):

it does for me, which version of Visual Studio are you using?

```
 Error  1   'New' cannot be used on a class that is declared 'MustInherit'. C:\Documents and Settings\---\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\---\Default.vb   171 39  ---
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not

```
Dim finalArray as New ArrayList()
```

Really, if you are only storing a certain type of object, you should be using generics.

```
Dim finalArray as New List(Of Integer)
Dim finalArray as New List(Of String)
Dim finalArray as New List(Of YourFavoriteObject)
```

(And dont be a sloppy VB6 programmer... add those perens for constructors and other methods calls.)

Comment: hes using array, not arraylist

Comment: you never know what he need to do, never assume anything :-)

Comment: Its pretty obvious that anyone doing .NET programming who is using an "Array" is not aware of the multitude of better choices for collections.

Comment: Arrays are so 2004.  Agree with Jack: if you see yourself using an array in .net, you should look at your code and see if you can do better.  One thing though: imo List<Object> is still preferrable to ArrayList.

Comment: If only params would give you the freedom to leave arrays in the dust...  =(

Answer (score 0):

You must specify type and size of the array:
Example creating array of `String`, size is 5:

```
Dim finalArray As Array = Array.CreateInstance(GetType(String), 5)
```